# Why bool("0") is true in python? why does this happen?

Tags: python, boolean

As I have started learning Python recently, I came across this boolean concept and I execute this expression `bool("0")`, but I got a confusing result as `True` of this expression, can anybody tell me why this happens.

Comment: It's explained here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bool("0")` evaluates to True because`"0"` in this case is a non-empty string. It's useful for things like :

```py
if str: #check if str is not empty
    #do something
```

`bool(0)` on the other hand evaluates to False.

Answer (score 1):

It is because it will return True for every non-empty strings,lists,etc.

Answer (score -1):

If int type varieble is zero Interpreter shows it as False .bool("0") evaluates to True because"0" in this case is a non-empty string,NOT int[See it full in one photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTgnK.png)

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31916897)